# How can one enable DES-encrypted keys on an Apple KDC?

Tags: mac-osx, kerberos, mac-osx-server, heimdal

We are running a KDC on OS X 10.10 Yosemite, to which we have added a service principal for remotely accessing a (legacy) host:

```
$ kadmin add -r host/a.b.c.d@REALM
```

Since the host only supports `des-cbc-crc` key encryption, we then tried (unsuccessfully) to add that:

```
$ kadmin add_enctype -r host/a.b.c.d@REALM des-cbc-crc
kadmin: bad enctype "des-cbc-crc"
```

Thinking that DES is (quite sensibly) disabled by default, we tried placing `allow_weak_crypto=true` in the `[libdefaults]` section of `/var/db/krb5kdc/kdc.conf` and restarting the `kdc` process, but to no avail.

Many hours have been spent thrashing around, but have born no fruit.  Surely Apple haven't compiled Kerberos without *any* support for DES?  How do we solve this?

Comment: Is [--disable-des](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/kdc.8.html) set?

Comment: @HopelessN00b: Good point.  No, it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Surely Apple haven't compiled Kerberos without any support for DES?

Well, actually, it looks like they did in 10.10/Yosemite.  And after the mess they made of Kerberos in 10.07/Lion... you have my sincere condolences.

[The functionality that krb5-weak.conf tries to achieve won't be needed on OS X from Yosemite (10.10) on forwards, since Yosemite's Kerberos removes the support for 1-DES encryption types and thus `allow_weak_crypto` does not have any effect whatsoever.  (We know this because of testing the beta versions and talking to Apple; this is one reason why we are in the process of rxkad'ing our AFS.)](https://lists.openafs.org/pipermail/openafs-devel/2014-August/019942.html)

[And here's another source](http://diswww.mit.edu:8008/menelaus.mit.edu/kerberos/36561), which contains a [handy link on upgrading older realms to modern crypto algorithms](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/admin/advanced/retiring-des.html).

Comment: Good find.  Now for a workaround...!